# How to plot a scatterplot with categorical variables in the x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a plot of weight in the y-axis by developmental stage in the x-axis. There are several hundred samples that contain data points at each developmental stage, and I'm trying to extract a growth rate curve from them. I don't know how to plot this in such a way that the x-axis represents three categorical variables ("ColonyMass_At_Wrkr_Eclosion", "ColonyMass_4wksLater", and "ColonyMass_2mnthsLater"), nor do I know how to connect the datapoints for the same individual across variables (such that a family of curves is created, if that makes sense). I've had some difficulty reproducing my dataframe using dput(), but I've tried my best. Any suggestions? Thank you so much!:

```
just_growth_data=structure(list(ColonyMass_At_Wrkr_Eclosion = c(NA, 117L, NA,     
53L, NA, 91L, 85L, 111L, 96L, NA, 112L, 90L, 112L, 120L, 110L, 
109L, NA, NA, 99L, 86L, 108L, 109L, 87L, 108L, 116L, 137L, 108L, 
NA, NA, NA, 93L, NA, 96L, 98L, 87L, NA, 111L, NA, 114L, NA, 11L, 
123L, 113L, 130L, 134L, NA, NA, 96L, NA, NA, 15L, 74L, NA, NA, 
75L, 96L, 88L, NA, 122L, NA, 101L, 83L, 123L, 89L, 85L, NA, 112L, 
98L, 87L, 123L, 115L, 16L, 125L, NA, 91L, NA, 85L, 76L, 122L, 
95L, 113L, 116L, 102L, 132L, 11L, 105L, 112L, 102L, 8L, NA, 113L, 
NA, 93L, 104L, 119L, 116L, 112L, 77L, NA, NA, 105L, 105L, 41L, 
99L, NA, 113L, 120L, 130L, 98L, 122L, 118L, NA, NA, 97L, NA, 
NA, NA, 104L, 103L, 110L, 25L, 118L, 98L, 123L, NA, 97L, NA, 
7L, 118L, NA, 82L, NA, 103L, 106L, 113L, NA, 115L, 123L, 124L, 
38L, 26L, 102L, 90L, NA, 59L, 102L, 82L, 120L, 113L, 116L, 117L, 
116L, 62L, 93L, 91L, 102L, 121L, 120L, NA, 111L, 97L, 63L, 109L, 
113L, 102L, 125L, 102L, 111L, 123L, 52L, 72L, NA, NA, 116L, NA, 
81L, 52L, 52L, NA, 105L, 123L, 87L, NA, 136L, 108L, NA, 120L, 
122L, NA, NA, 126L, NA, 47L, 111L, 118L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 109L, 
NA, 99L, 106L, 53L, 102L, 77L, 99L, NA, NA, NA, 114L, NA, 111L, 
NA, 113L, NA, 76L, 114L, NA, 120L, 113L, 97L, 134L, 98L, 118L, 
75L, 109L, 124L, 108L, NA, 124L, NA, 65L, 100L, NA, NA, 126L, 
11L, 97L, 76L, NA, NA, 106L, 110L, 3L, 116L, NA, NA, 135L, 96L, 
101L, NA, 92L, NA, NA, 118L, NA, 105L, 15L, 129L, 128L, 102L, 
NA, 92L, 100L, NA, NA, 71L, 103L, NA, 113L, NA, NA, 63L, NA, 
88L, 83L, 106L, 117L, 49L, NA, NA, 61L, 79L, NA, 91L, 102L, NA, 
93L, NA, NA, NA, 87L, 126L, 99L, NA, NA, 100L, 116L, 103L, 87L, 
37L, NA, 112L, NA, NA, 18L, NA, 94L, NA, NA, NA, 117L, 102L, 
62L, 96L, NA, 87L, 8L, NA, 86L, 61L, NA, 68L, 117L, 89L, NA, 
90L, NA, 104L, 94L, 102L, NA, 105L, 107L, 62L, 130L, 99L, 111L, 
NA, 106L, 98L, NA, 140L, 88L, 94L, NA, 122L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ColonyMass_4wksLater = c(NA, 
571L, NA, NA, NA, 736L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 438L, NA, NA, 711L, 
NA, NA, NA, 537L, NA, 844L, NA, NA, NA, 560L, 561L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 594L, NA, NA, 457L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 714L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 417L, 
NA, NA, NA, 701L, NA, NA, NA, 25L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 866L, NA, NA, 291L, NA, 659L, 354L, 743L, NA, NA, 696L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 518L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 907L, 
27L, NA, NA, 625L, NA, NA, 957L, 804L, NA, NA, NA, 650L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 699L, 632L, NA, NA, 518L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 527L, 541L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 448L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 382L, NA, 431L, NA, 620L, 
NA, 296L, NA, 532L, NA, 485L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 153L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 23L, NA, NA, NA, 606L, NA, NA, NA, 550L, 766L, NA, 
426L, 786L, NA, NA, 289L, NA, 119L, 327L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 602L, NA, 20L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 152L, NA, 592L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1235L, 197L, NA, 442L, NA, NA, 558L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 818L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 783L, NA, 519L, NA, 
NA, NA, 856L, 609L, NA, 397L, NA, NA, 1195L, NA, 473L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 370L, NA, NA, 3L, 561L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 783L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 537L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
937L, NA, 696L, NA, NA, 859L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 902L, 430L, NA, 11L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 354L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 682L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 134L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 670L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 537L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ColonyMass_2mnthsLater = c(NA, 
445L, NA, NA, NA, 1817L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2683L, NA, NA, 1775L, 
NA, NA, NA, 429L, NA, 77L, NA, NA, NA, 279L, 23L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 111L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 70L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 71L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 249L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1249L, 636L, 710L, NA, NA, 27L, NA, 
50L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 531L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 63L, NA, 
NA, NA, 416L, NA, NA, 400L, 902L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 116L, NA, NA, NA, 674L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1439L, 305L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 93L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1107L, NA, 13L, NA, 201L, 
NA, 470L, NA, 184L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 72L, NA, NA, NA, 2727L, 33L, NA, 121L, 643L, 
NA, NA, 168L, NA, 160L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1732L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 666L, 
60L, NA, 128L, NA, NA, 140L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1726L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1966L, NA, NA, NA, 77L, 76L, NA, 
199L, NA, NA, 54L, NA, 377L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
738L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1422L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 695L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15L, NA, 1058L, NA, 
NA, 680L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 534L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 850L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 146L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("ColonyMass_At_Wrkr_Eclosion", "ColonyMass_4wksLater", 
"ColonyMass_2mnthsLater"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-622L))

just_growth_data_factor<-factor(c("ColonyMass_At_Wrkr_Eclosion", "ColonyMass_4wksLater", "ColonyMass_2mnthsLater"))
x<-rep(just_growth_data_factor,622)
qplot(just_growth_data_factor, x)
```

Comment: Why are all your weights coded as factors in the output of `dput`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I read the dataframe using read.csv, if that helps.

Comment: Are the weights supposed to be continuous (numeric)? At the moment there are  between 300 and 500 missing values in each column is this correct? If not, try setting `na.string` correctly within the `read.csv` call.

Comment: only a small subset of the samples contain data for some of these measures. What do you mean "setting na.string correctly"? I'm a bit confused about why it would be a problem to keep them as NAs, I guess.

Comment: One step at a time: Fix the data before you try to plot it. From your question, the weight values sounds like they are numeric not factors, the difference is important to R and ggplot2.

Comment: I am only trying to understand your data - NA values are not a problem if they are actually NA values. Until you get the data in a form that makes sense, nobody can help without making assumptions. One of your labels is ` NA` (space NA) so you need to clean up your data so it represents what you want. That is not the job of Stackoverflowites.

Comment: I very much appreciate the help. I'm still so new to R that it's difficult for me to figure out even those kinds of problems still. I believe that the dataframe is in good shape now (code edited above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# add an id column (presumably rows are individuals)
just_growth_data$id <- 1:nrow(just_growth_data)

# melt the data, collapsing the three categorical columns down into two:
# variable (the column name) and value (the column value)
require(reshape)
data.m <- melt(just_growth_data, id.vars="id")

# a simple scatterplot with the original rows connected
ggplot(data.m, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=id)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image: a plot from cleaned up data]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!
Any suggestions for how to fit a logistic curve to this with confidence intervals? Or should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: And is there any way to do this in Base R, or is ggplot pretty much essential to do this?

Comment: @Atticus29: Post a separate question for the logistic curve fitting, as it doesn't really fit under your original question. Most ggplot graphs are doable in base R, but ggplot is preferred by a lot of people because the syntax is so much easier to understand, and more expressive once you do understand it. If you haven't invested too much time in learning the base plotting system, I'd recommend switching to ggplot ASAP.